# Different models, same data, in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart

We have an ASP.NET MVC website with two main models /Account and /Store. Account model is dedicated to user registration, password recovery, profile update, etc. while the Store one is dedicated to shopping cart and checkout management.

During the purchase process, we want to give the user the ability to login (and eventually recover password), update his/her profile data, etc. This involves accessing the data of the /Account model and the need to return to the original purchase process page.

What is the best way to accomplish this (jump elsewhere and return) with MVC?

Thanks,

Alberto

Comment: No offense, but I would strongly recommend you NOT to develop e-commerce application yourself with your current level of knowledge (you cant even tell difference between controller and model in MVC).

Comment: @rouen: I am not developing by myself, I am trying to sort out something that MVC developers cannot. Do you know the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alberto,
If these classes are really models then you have no problem to use them in any controller.
The best way is to use partial views and just invoke them from your controller.

I hope this helps you, let me know if you require more clarification.

Alexander

Comment: What about returning to the original page after - for example - have updated the user profile.